# Recursive Function to print in a certain way

Tags: c++, recursion

Full disclosure: This is a hw problem, I prefer you provided the least amount of code to explain the problem and I appreciate any help I get.

Basically I have to write a function that prints out 2^n-1 items recursively in the following fashion:

```
The output if n=1 is: 1
The output if n=2 is: 1 2 1
The output if n=3 is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
The output if n=4 is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

I have no clue how I can go about doing this. I was playing around with Fibonacci series but that seemed like a dead end. Thanks!

Comment: I hope it clear you'll be recursing twice, both before, and after, the current `n` is printed. And consider the base case, which should ideally do *nothing* when it reaches zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** 
Analyse the problem first. You found out it needs recursion.

**Step 2:**
Find out the recursive scheme and build a hypothesis:
for `n==2` your answer is `1 2 1` , for `n==3` ans is `1 2 1 3 1 2 1` then you suddenly notice that for `n==3` you are writing first answer for `n==2` and then `3` and again answer for `n==2`
so by now your hypothesis will be ans for n-1 then n and again answer for n-1

**Step 3:**
Verify the Hypothesis:
now you should verify whether you are right or not. you checked for n=2 and n=4 and whoa! you find expected answer. Now you have a verified hypothesis of recursion. Go ahead and write a code.

**Step 4:**
writing down the code:
first find out base case: here it is n=1 because you cannot go deeper.
so our function starts like:

```
void foo(int n){
    if(n==1){
        cout<<1;
        return ;
    }
}
```

now use our hypothesis, write down the remaining code.

```
void foo(int n){
    if(n==1){
        cout<<1;
        return ;
    }
    foo(n-1);        //our hypothesis say first we need to write the answer for n-1
    cout<<" "<<n<<" ";  //then writing n itself
    foo(n-1);    //again writing answer for n-1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should work as a in-place walk on a full binary tree. It is like you have the following tree:

```
        3
    2       2
  1   1   1   1
```

The tree is reflected having the same value in each level.
So your function will should be like:

```
void func(int n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    cout << "1 ";
    return;
  }

  func(n - 1);
  cout << n << ' ';
  func(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine but he asked for limited code and lots of explination. You just gave the straight up answer.

Comment: "I prefer you provided the least amount of code to explain the problem and I appreciate any help I get."

Comment: BTW no need for -1. If you didn't like the answer, just don't upvote. Use your downvotes to incorrect answers.

Comment: You gave the full answer. This is not the least amount of code because he can literally just copy paste this and it will work. Hence why I consider it to be a bad answer worthy of the -1

Comment: Improved the answer. Better now?

Comment: +1 I have to admit the picture of the BST as it relates to the symmetry of how the algorithm works is pretty well done. I can totally see (in my head) another 3-level tree to the right of this one with a 4 hanging over the top of both.

Comment: Given the question is far from clear about the *why*, this seems like pretty good answer to the *how*.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig but I corrected the answer as it is not a BST like tree. It is more like an heap :).

Comment: @sheddenizen I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos oops, sorry I didn't realize 'hw' meant homework - it all makes much more sense now :). Anyway, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is already an answer given anyway, here is a short version:

```
bool f(int i)
{
    return i && (f(i-1), std::cout << i << ' ', f(i-1));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the short-circuit evaluation, and the comma operator. nice touch, although if the OP is having problems with the recursion, this is libel to cause convulsions =}

Comment: @WhozCraig: My understanding is that we are not in the business of providing homework solutions which can readily be handed in. If I'd get presented that solution I'd surely ask about how it works and if the OP understands that all is good.

Comment: Absolutely. They *better* understand it if they hand something like this in. Hard to fake your way through it if you don't. There's a lot going on in that little line of code.

Comment: Thanks for this. No way I am going to use this. The first answer was totally what i was looking for: how to analyze the problem. But this is something I am going to have fun deciphering!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you are trying to cover each number with its lesser number (and that number will repeat the same process through recursion for itself) until the parameter (n) reaches 0. In which case it will just return without doing anything.

The code will look like this:

```
void sequence(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    sequence(n-1);
    cout << n << ' ';
    sequence(n-1);
}
```